# Is Page Object Pattern suitable for Windows Application

Tags: winforms, wpf-controls, coded-ui-tests, pageobjects, testautomationfx

I have read that Page Object Pattern is suitable for the Web Application Automation and I have used the Page object pattern with Selenium for one of the Web Apps I have automated.

How ever I am curious to know is Page Object suitable to Windows/Desktop applications  ?. Though there is a scope in Windows Apps as well to create different Top level Windows as Pages and expose the operations as methods.

Has any one tried this and want to know the experiences/Advantages/disadvantages

Answer (score 3):

The key equivalence here is page <=> dialog.

In a web app you encapsulate each page in a page object, while in a desktop app you encapsulate each dialog in an object that you might call a "dialog object".

The point is the encapsulation.

Over at my blog I've written about DRY page objects for testing web apps, but if you substitute *dialog* for *page*, it will apply equally well to dialog objects for desktop apps:

-- [Keep Your Page Objects Clean and DRY](http://burdettelamar.wordpress.com/2014/03/21/keep-your-page-objects-dry/)

Answer (score 0):

yes we can automate the desktop based application with Page object. you can refer [WinAppDriverPageObjectModel](https://www.automatetheplanet.com/winappdriver-page-objects/)